# RightJS: getElementById vs $('element_id')

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, rightjs

I am learning javascript and using RightJS. What is the difference between the following?

```
var thing = $('thing1')
```

and

```
var thing = document.getElementById('thing1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type it into the browser's console

```
> $("head")
  by {_: div#head, constructor: function, initialize: function, parent: function, parents: function…}
> document.getElementById("head");
  <div id=​"head">​…​</div>​
```

You can see the $ returns some sort of wrapped object and that getElementById returns an Html Node.

Check out their docs on [Util.$](http://rightjs.org/docs/util#%24)